# Integrating an Infinite exponent tower

Tags: calculus, integration, power-towers

$$ \int_0^1 x^{2^{x^{2^{x^{\ldots}}}}} ~~ dx =  ~~?$$

[image: An Image of the function (until a certain amount of iterations)]
             
                                                                 [image]

---

### What I've tried so far:

$$ x^{2^{x^{2 \ldots}}} \overbrace{=}^{\text{def}} y \\ x^{2^{y}} = y \\ 2^y \ln (x) = \ln(y)$$

**Now applying the chain rule:**

$$\begin{align} \\&2^y \cdot \frac{dy}{dx} \cdot \ln(2) \cdot \ln(x) + \frac{1}{x} \cdot 2^y \ln(y) =  \frac{dy}{dx} \cdot \frac1y \\ &\implies \frac{dy}{dx} \left (2^y \cdot \ln(x)  \cdot \ln(2) - \frac1y \right) = - \frac1x 2^y \cdot \ln(y) \\ &\implies \frac{dy}{dx} = \left ( \frac{- \frac1x 2^y \cdot \ln(y)}{2^y \cdot \ln(x)  \cdot \ln(2) - \frac1y} \right) \end{align}$$

The problem that this looks like a pretty harsh equation to solve for $dy$ and then substitute it back to the integral, with the fact that we need to find the value of $x$ in terms of $y$.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you looking for an exact solution or a numerical approximation?

Comment: @openproblem Well, there is no problem approximate it using a script or plugging it some kind of a site like Wolfram-Alpha so I guess the problem is to find an exact solution for this. Of course, if it is not possible (I don't know if it is, but maybe -and probably- I don't have all the tools or knowledge to solve this) then I would assume an approximation would do the job!

Comment: Where does the problem come from? Could you give some context?

Comment: The inner function in the photo seems not correct (why there is $x^x$). Besides, I plot the inner function and didn't obtain the same plot you gave.

Comment: @NN2 My bad, but they looks roughly the same because the exponent grows too fast to notice, that was a misclick, I meant by doing $2$ and $x$ iteratively. Are you sure you are not plotting $((x^2)^x)^2 \dots$ by accident?

Comment: I construct the function as follows. $f_1(x)=x^2$ and $f_n(x)=(f_{n-1}(x))^{x^2} $. After that, I plot these functions $f_n(x)$. But these plots are really diffrent the one you plotted. Besides, it seems to me that the integral converges to 1. Your integral seems to converge to $\frac{1}{2}$. PS: how do you have this problem?

Comment: @NN2 This is not the recurrence relation, for example for $f_2$ you will get $f_2(x) = (f_1 (x))^{x^2} = (x^2)^{x^2}$ this is not equal to $x^{2^{x^2}}$. I don't have a source of context unfortunately!

Comment: Ok I see. your graphic is correct.

Answer (score 4):

We can transform this to an integral of an elementary function:
\begin{align}
\int_0^1ydx&=[xy]_0^1-\int_0^1xdy\\
&=1-\int_0^1y^{1/(2^y)}dy.\\
\end{align}
However, I don't think there is a closed-form to this integral since Wolfram Alpha doesn't show anything. I tried to use some series expansion, but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: Awesome this is an improvement because we got rid of this ugly infinite power tower!

Comment: Series work quite well. In any manner, (+1) for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Consider
$$I=\int_0^1 y^{2^{-y}}\,dy=\int_0^\frac 12 y^{2^{-y}}\,dy-\int_1^\frac 12 y^{2^{-y}}\,dy=I_1-I_2$$
Each integrand will be developed as a series expansion around the lower bound to order $(n+1)$ and termwise integrated. This does not lead to very complicated expressions for the integrands and the result of integration is just a polynomial in $\log(2)$.

For example, for $n=3$, the integrands are
$$y-y^2 \log (2) \log (y)+\frac{1}{2} y^3 \left(\log ^2(2) \log ^2(y)+\log ^2(2) \log
   (y)\right)+O\left(y^4\right)$$
$$1+\frac{y-1}{2}+(y-1)^2 \left(-\frac{1}{8}-\frac{\log (2)}{2}\right)+(y-1)^3
   \left(\frac{1}{16}+\frac{\log ^2(2)}{4}\right)+O\left((y-1)^4\right)$$

and the result of integration is
$$\frac{5127+72 \log ^4(2)-36 \log ^3(2)+339 \log ^2(2)-64 \log (2)}{9216}$$
As a function of order $n$, some results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & I_1-I_2 \\
 1 & 0.56250000 \\
 2 & 0.57249702 \\
 3 & 0.56967702 \\
 4 & 0.56945295 \\
 5 & 0.56962947 \\
 6 & 0.56968187 \\
 7 & 0.56969293 \\
 8 & 0.56969494 \\
 9 & 0.56969522 \\
 10 & 0.56969526 \\
 11 & 0.56969527 \\
 12 & 0.56969528     
\end{array}
\right)$$